# Outlook VBA save attachements Run-time error -2147287032 (80030008) and than delete it

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a vba to save attachements from selected emails taken from here ;)
The code does exactly what I need until I select higher number of emails. The number vary and I think it is related to number of attachements. Than VBA Run-time error -2147287032 (80030008) happens on this line

```
 objAttachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile strFile
```

```
Public Sub SaveAttachments()
Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
Dim objMsg As Outlook.MailItem 'Object
Dim objAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
Dim objSelection As Outlook.Selection
Dim i As Long
Dim lngCount As Long
Dim strFile As String
Dim strFolderpath As String
Dim strDeletedFiles As String

    Set objOL = Application

    Set objSelection = objOL.ActiveExplorer.Selection

    For Each objMsg In objSelection
          
    If InStr(objMsg, "case1") > 0 Then
            strFolderpath = "C:\case1"
    End If
   
    If InStr(objMsg, "case2") > 0 Then
            strFolderpath = "C:\case2"
    End If

    Set objAttachments = objMsg.Attachments
    lngCount = objAttachments.Count
        
    If lngCount > 0 Then
    
    For i = lngCount To 1 Step -1
    
    strFile = objAttachments.Item(i).FileName
    strFile = strFolderpath & strFile
    objAttachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile strFile
    
    Next i
    End If
    
    Next
    
ExitSub:

Set objAttachments = Nothing
Set objMsg = Nothing
Set objSelection = Nothing
Set objOL = Nothing
```

Seems to me like I have to clean up some variable, but I am not able to find which one and where...

Another task I want to aquire would be to delete processed email (simple move to deleted is enough)

Obviously objMail.Delete would do the work, but I have failed to integrate it into the code.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If none of the following is executed:

```
If InStr(objMsg, "case1") > 0 Then
            strFolderpath = "C:\case1"
End If
   
If InStr(objMsg, "case2") > 0 Then
            strFolderpath = "C:\case2"
End If
```

You may end up with `strFolderpath` not initialized correctly. So, I'd suggest setting the default value:

```
Dim strFolderpath As String = "C:\case"
```

Make sure the path string passed to the [SaveAsFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachment.saveasfile) method is a valid file path.

Comment: Is your drive out of capacity? make sure there are sufficient memory slot available for storing the files attached.

Comment: definitely not, there are ~50GB of free space and I am working with ~500MB of emails. Operating memory does not change at all running the script and there is always at least ~1GB of free memory

Comment: Did you have a chance to check the [Attachment.Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachment.type) property before saving to the disk?

Answer (score 0):

The error code is `STG_E_INSUFFICIENTMEMORY`. Are you trying to save to save an attachment other then `olByValue`? You can end up with an `olOle` attachment, which cannot be saved using `Attachment.SaveAsFile`. Do check the `Attachment.Type` property first.

Another possibility is that you are running of RPC channels in case of an online (as opposed to cached) Exchange store. Make sure you release all variables as soon as you are done with them to avoid RPC - otherwise the objects are released when they go out of scope when the sub exits.

```
Set objAttachments = objMsg.Attachments
For i = lngCount To 1 Step -1
  set objAttach = objAttachments.Item(i)
  strFile = objAttach.FileName
  strFile = strFolderpath & strFile
  objAttach.SaveAsFile strFile
  set objAttach = Nothing
Next i
set objAttachments = Nothing
```

Comment: This is far away from mine VBA skills, so I cannot fully respond, but I do not think this is the problem. The code never stop on certain email. Let say I have 200 mails to process. When I select them all I get the error. When I process same emails during two runs 100+100 they are processed just fine...

Comment: Nope :/ But something changed - the error is now -2147024882 (8007000e) I have 2GB free memory and during the run it barely moves

Comment: The error is MAPI_E_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY. What is the latest version of your code?